# Visual Studio Mac Azure Functions Permission denied

Tags: macos, function, permissions, tmp

I try to run a simple Azure function on my Visual Studio for mac, and I get an error stating permission denied to the tmp file (that I assume is the file VS creates to simulate the local storage)

Error looks like this:

> Blockquote
>   Error: Unable to connect to the specified connection id.
>   bash: /tmp/tmp47179b7.tmp: Permission denied
>   logout
>   Saving session...
>   ...copying shared history...
>   ...saving history...truncating history files...
>   ...completed.

If I go to the tmp folder, indeed I have that file created and it is created with the following permissions:
system : Read & Write
everyone : No access

I am not sure how to make VS create that file with correct permissions, because that's probablly the cause of the error.